# Change HTML POST port

Tags: html, post

I have a form in an HTML document whose contents I would like to submit to the server as a POST request. However, I would like to send the POST request to a port on the server other than port 80. Is this possible?

Comment: Note that server must be listening on that port!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just append it to the action

`<form method="post" action="http://myserver.com:1234/postHandler.php"....`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible:

```
<form action="http:/myserver:7778/process" method="post">
```